# How to export a map (satellite image, 3 bands) to Tiff without losing the resolution in Qgis.

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, landsat, kmz

I manually improve the colour contrast of landsat images. The printing in pdf afterwards is OK, as it maintains the resolution due to the high dpi. Now I am interested to obtain a kmz/kml file of the satelite image for visualization in Google Earth. I have downloaded Maptiller which allows to load in tiff, and generate kmz. My problem, however, is that saving the map as tiff results in a maximum image size of 2.3MB, hence the resolution gets lost before the actual conversion to kmz. I used the garmincustommap plugin of Qgis, but same issue...Seems that the only straightforward way would be arcGis or globalmapper, which I do not have access to. Any suggestions?

Comment: kml and kmz s have a limited capacity as a standalone file. Kmz s which refer to a server resource can allow Google Earth to display extensive imagey.   You may need to consider what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Right Clic on your raster>Save as>GTiff (try to keep Output Mode in Raw Data)

[image: Save Raster Layer as]